# SQL Server : update column based on similar column

Tags: sql-server

We're using SQL Server 2008, a sample of the table. I am trying to cleanup (then will delete duplicates later) where the `prev_date` column is different when `item#` is the same. I want to update both records with the `max(prev_date)` value. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this for multiple records with a single statement

```
key                     item(int)             prev_date(int)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
15086                           1163            20121023
16289                           1163            20130121
15087                           1164            20121024
16290                           1164            20130120
15088                           1165            20121029
16291                           1165            20130120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE provides a clean SQL

```
;with cte_max(item, maxdate) as (
 select item, max(prev_date) from t
 group by item
)
update t
    set prev_date = m.maxdate
  from t
    inner join cte_max m on t.item = m.item 
 where t.prev_date <> m.maxdate
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

```
update a set a.date=b.date from table_1 as a 
inner join 
(select *,row_number() over(partition by item order by date desc)as rownum from table_1  
)b 
on a.item=b.item and b.rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For these types of updates, I like to use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate (
      select t.*, max(prev_date) over (partition by item) as new_prev_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set prev_date = new_prev_date
    where prev_date <> new_prev_date;  -- optional `where` clause
```

There are other approaches.  Standard SQL would be:

```
update t
    set prev_date = (select max(prev_date) from t t2 where t2.item = t.item);
```